# localStorage : store checkboxes automatically checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have something like this in php:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']){ 
            $check = in_array($row['service_object_id'], $values) ? 'checked' : ''; 
    }                       
    echo '<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" id="'.$row['service_object_id'].'" name="list[]" value="'.$row['service_object_id'].'" '.$check.'>';
```

Each time I press a submit button, it will check the checkboxes with values inside `$check`.
It's working good but I want to store the checkboxes checked in localStorage automatically after pressing the button.

I already use this script to store them after click, but it won't work automatically :

```
    <script type = "text/javascript"> 
$('.faChkRnd').on('click', function() {
  var fav, favs = [];
  $('.faChkRnd').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
    fav = {id: $(this).attr('id'), value: $(this).prop('checked')};
    favs.push(fav);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favs));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  if (!favorites.length) {return};
  console.debug(favorites);

  for (var i=0; i<favorites.length; i++) {
    console.debug(favorites[i].value == 'on');
    $('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked', favorites[i].value);
  }
});
</script>
```

Any ideas ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shound check type of `favorites[i].value`. string or boolean !?

string :

```
if(favorites[i].value == "true") {
    $('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked',true);
}
```

boolean :

```
$('#' + favorites[i].id ).prop('checked',favorites[i].value);
```

example :

string : https://jsfiddle.net/utm4za2p/1/

boolean : https://jsfiddle.net/utm4za2p/3/

Comment: With this solution it will clear the localStorage after I refresh the page since I get the value of checkboxes that need to be checked only after I submit a button. I have found an alternative solution without JS : I store my $check values into a SESSION... If you think you can solve this with JS don't be shy :)

Comment: if you refresh the page, you have to save data into session or cookie to set it into checkboxes
same as : `var localStorage = sessionStorage;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use submit method.
You have a form with the submit button and you have to change it to just a regular button.

And you should put

```
$('.yourForm').submit()
```

to the end of click handler where you save the values to the localStorage.

Because when you press the submit button it may triggered before your click handler.
You need save values first and then submit form.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but for some reason it will store every values in localStorage as "false". I have found an alternative solution without JS : I store my $check values into a SESSION... If you think you can solve this with JS don't be shy :)

Comment: Well I have made working prototype [link](https://jsfiddle.net/a7mk62sw/1/). I have found bug in your code but I don't sure that was a cause of problem. You want to store your checkbox statuses to localStorage when you click on some checkbox. For example you have 2 checkboxes but if you click two times on checkbox you put in localStorage 4 records because you put status in array each time you click on checkbox. Old values will store also. I think it may cause the problems. Therefore I have changed favs to object and use id as a key. You can analyze my code I hope it will help you.